# Additional Network Interface card in Linux VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, kali-linux, azure-linux

I have deployed a Kali Linux VM in Azure and created an addition network interface card, however when i type ifconfig in terminal I cannot see the new network interface card I attached?

Comment: Maybe you can provide more details? such as the screenshot of the ifconfig?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to added Nic to a Linux VM correctly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-network%2ftoc.json#add-a-nic-to-a-vm

To make sure you do not run into issues it is better to add Nic while VM is deallocated.

Comment: Sorry about that, i could have sworn it worked before.  Just tested it seem (atleat with latest) you have to manually bring up the interface. Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/zdXT7aYF0C6 Commands: https://codepad.co/snippet/kali-linux